# C++ Stack using template

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list, template, stack

I'm learning C++, so I wrote a stack with the help of templates. I'm wondering if there is anything I can improve or if I did something vastly wrong.

**Stack.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <ostream>

template <class Type>
struct Node {
    Node(Type data, Node<Type>* next) 
        : data(data), next(next) {}
    Node* next;
    Type data;
};

template <class Type>
class Stack
{
public:

    Stack() : length(0), topNode(NULL) {
    }

    ~Stack() {
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            pop();
        }
    }

    void push(Type data) {
        Node<Type>* newNode = new Node<Type>(data, topNode);
        topNode = newNode;
        ++length;
    }

    Type pop() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            Node<Type>* popped = topNode;
            Type poppedData = popped->data;
            topNode = popped->next;
            --length;
            delete popped;
            return poppedData;
        }

        throw new std::exception("Stack underflow!");
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        return length == 0;
    }

    void print() const {
        Node<Type>* tempTop = topNode;
        while (tempTop != NULL) {
            std::cout << tempTop->data << endl;
            tempTop = tempTop->next;
        }
    }

    int count() const {
        return length;
    }

private:
    Node<Type>*         topNode;
    int                 length;

};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Stack<int> myStack;

    // Push some values
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(4);
    myStack.push(8);
    myStack.push(16);
    myStack.push(32);

    // We pop the 32
    myStack.pop(); 

    // Display count after the pop
    int lastPopped = myStack.pop();
    cout << "Popped value: " << lastPopped << ", Count: " << myStack.count() << endl; 

    // Print whole stack
    cout << endl << "Stack print: " << endl;
    myStack.print(); 

    // Exit program when the 'any' key is pressed.
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you provide a destructor you should handle copying and assigning. In other words follow the *Rule of 3* (or 5 if you care about move semantics). You can also disallow them but then there should be move constructor and assignment.

Otherwise you will get in trouble with double freeing when calling a function `void foo(Stack<int> s)`.

---

`empty()` doesn't change the stack. So it should also be `const`.

Consider adding a `peek()` method that returns a reference to the top value of the stack (with const and non-const version).

```
T& peek()
{
    return topNode->data;
}

const T& peek() const
{
    return topNode->data;
}
```

The reason for using the reference is to avoid a unnecessary copy.

---

Having a print method interacting with the console is not a good idea. What if you want to show the contents in a gui instead?

Instead add iterators to be able to inspect what is on the stack without having to capture the output that `print()` generates.

Comment: I guess you mean `T&` (and `const T&`) instead of `&T` (and `const &T`) ?

Answer (score 8):

## Include guards

Rather than relying on `#pragma once`, you should use an include guard in your `Stack.h` file instead, like this:

```
#ifndef STACK_TYPE_H_
#define STACK_TYPE_H_

// Original code for Stack.h goes here.

#endif
```

While `#pragma once` is supported across many compilers, there's always the chance that there is one that doesn't support it because it still isn't standard. If you feel the need to use both `#pragma once` and include guards, just do something like this:

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_
#pragma once

// Original code for Stack.h goes here.

#endif
```

---

## Passing by `const` reference

If you never modify the value of an argument when you pass it, like in the `push` function:

> ```
> void push(Type data) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Rather than passing the value normally, you should pass it by `const` reference, like this:

```
void push(const Type& data) 
{
    ...
}
```

While this is a micro-optimization for *"small"* types, like `int`, or `bool`, when you start dealing with *"bigger"* types, like `std::string`, or a user-defined type, doing this becomes a little more important.

---

## Nitpicks

While your test file containing `main` isn't such a huge deal, there are still a few bad things I want to point out about it.

First off, this line:

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Is as really bad habit to get into. It can also result in many bad things happening, especially if you're using Boost, which provides alternatives to some of the functions in `std`. Some of the bad things that can happen can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

This line here should be removed as well:

> ```
> system("PAUSE");
> ```

Preferably if you need to display output for the user to see, you should use something like this instead:

```
std::cin.get();
```

`system("PAUSE");` is bad, for the following reasons:

- It's slow and un-optimal.
- It's insecure.
- It's very platform-dependent.

Preferably, as it is the C++ style, you should define you class and it's function/constructor signatures inside `Stack.h`, and then create a file named `Stack.cpp` where you implement the function/constructors.

Finally, your `isEmpty` function should be `const`, since it isn't modifying anything. That means that this:

> ```
> bool isEmpty() {
>     return length == 0;
> }
> ```

Should become this:

```
bool isEmpty() const {
    return length == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The curly braces seem very subjective to me as the community do 50/50.

Also Why is System("Pause") bad?

And I wrote everything in the header file because I couldn't get Templates to work with it.

Comment: @Caresi No problem! The curly braces thing is an opinion of mine, and I also find it easier to read. I will edit to explain system("pause") in a second.

Comment: @Caresi Added explanation.

Comment: I see! Thank you. As far as I've read templates doesn't work with implementation(.cpp). If that is correct

Comment: `#pragma once` offers so many advantages over guards that I strongly disagree that guards should be used in the general case. The choice between `#pragma once` is one that deserves some consideration, not just “use guards because they always work!” (because they *don’t*, in the far-more-likely case of name conflicts).

Comment: @KRyan I am aware of that. That's why I provided an alternative which uses both include guards **and** `#pragma once`. I hardly think that suggesting include guards is worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @EthanBierlein I disagree, clearly, since I downvoted. Your suggestion of both does little to help in the case of name conflict, since the unit still won’t pass the guards if a name conflict has already `#define STACK_H_`’d.

Comment: @KRyan `#pragma once` does not offer *so many* advantages. Name conflicts are orthogonal. That means that you didn't use namespaces properly and you should feel bad about it :( Also, from a speed point of view, GCC at least recognizes include guards and is able to make proper optimizations too.

Comment: @Morwenn The preprocessor does not have any notion of namespaces, and if you have two files that use `#ifndef STACK_H_` `#define STACK_H_` in the same compilation, one of them is not going to be included (or, at least, nothing between the guards will be). Keeping track of all of the guard names in your compilation (including those of any third-party libraries that are being included) to avoid this is a large burden, one that should be taken on *only* when truly necessary (i.e. you really do need this to be compilable on those few compilers that don’t support `#pragma once`).

Comment: @KRyan Agreed, `STACK_H_` is too short, but if you prefix the name of your library and this of the path of the file, you aren't likely to have a problem and it isn't hard to keep track of it (sorry for misinterpreting your argument at first). Above all, it's a matter of values: I believe that one should *always* strive to achieve standard compliance first. I reckon that it's not everybody's stance.

Comment: @KRyan I've changed the name of `STACK_H_` to `STACK_TYPE_H`, if it helps.

Comment: Ethan and @Morwenn: A longer name only reduces the risk, it doesn’t actually eliminate it. Eliminating it means developing a project-wide standard for naming that is strictly adhered to (and that won’t conflict with any libraries, which hopefully have a decent and documented standard themselves). That is decidedly non-negligible work, and the bugs caused by problems with it can be devilish to track down in some cases. Standards compliance is, of course, extremely important, but ultimately I consider the lack of `#pragma once` in the standard to be a serious deficiency in the standard.

Comment: @KRyan No, seriously, a longer name reduces it *as much as a namespace does*, so you generally just have to check that there isn't a library with the same name as yours (a quick search in a search engine and you're done). I've never heard of two serious libraries with conflicting header guard names. There isn't any plan to standardize `#pragma once` because there is work to standardize modules, but it probably won't be finished for the next revision of the standard. Also, having a consistent naming scheme *should be something to strive for* anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This is my first code review, anyway.

1. `struct Node`

   I would have put in namespace detail or made this class a private nested class in your `Stack`
2. `void push(Type data)`

   Is your Stack only for int or for user defined types also? This push is OK for ints and doubles but for user defined types I would have written:

   ```
   void push(const Type& data)
   ```
3. `Type pop()`

   Since copying an instance of Type might throw I would have created

   ```
   Type& front();
   void pop();
   ```
4. `throw new std::exception("Stack underflow!");`

   If I am correct `std::exception` has no constructor `std::exception(const char*)`, so use `std::runtime_exception`.
5. `throw new std::exception("Stack underflow!");`

   Do not use `new`, just write

   ```
   throw std::runtime_exception("Stack underflow!");
   ```

   http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321113586/items/sutter_item73.pdf
6. You should provided copy constructor and the assignment operator for Stack. If it is C++11 then also move constructor and move assigment
7. Since your `pop()` returns a value you can clear your stack in `~Stack()` in more lightweight way

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your intressting details!
1 and 5 is pretty forward however I'm very curious on how #2 and #3 will benefit and why the C++ version matters?

Comment: Also why should I provide a copy constructor and assigment?

Comment: Aside from Caresi's questions, it's generally good practice to explain the benefits of the changes you're suggesting. Just telling someone to change their code doesn't teach them a lot.